# VARIABLE__CRED: unbound variable - bash script can't find global variable

Tags: node.js, bash, ubuntu

I use ssh connection to server(ubuntu)

In `~/.bash_profile` stored global variable **VARIABLE__CRED** as `VARIABLE__CRED="my-token"`

Using node.js I run project as `pnpm start`

Inside project starting initialize bash script bin/getData:

```
decoded_credentials=$(echo -e "${VARIABLE__CRED}" | sed 's/%40/@/g')

curl -L -u "$decoded_credentials" -XGET "https://company.jfrog.io/artifactory/project-schema/schema.json" --output "./schema.json"
```

Returns error as `bin/getData: line 10: VARIABLE__CRED: unbound variable`

I tried in terminal to run manually command `echo -e "${VARIABLE__CRED}" | sed 's/%40/@/g'` and was returned value with my token that was stored in bash_profile.

before running `pnpm start` I run command `source ~/.bash_profile` but the same error.

Could you please help to figure out why script can't find this global variable.

Comment: bash doesn't really have truly global variables. If you're actually setting the variable with just `VARIABLE__CRED="my-token"` in ~/.bash_profile, that variable will only be available in interactive login bash shells, and something run from node.js is not going to be one of those. `export`ing the variable would make it an environment variable, so programs run *from* a interactive login shell would inherit copies of it, but I don't know if that would inherit through `pnpm start`.

Comment: To complement the valid comment of Gordon Davisson: bash variables exist only in the bash process where they get defined.  The only way to have a child process - be it bash or something else - to have read access to the variable, is to put the variable into the environment. This is a general Linux mechanism, not specific to bash.

Comment: Thank you for response. How to put the variable into the environment? You mean in project create local env and use it?

Comment: Each process inherits its environment from whatever process started it. So if your program is executed from a shell, it'll inherit that shell's environment; if it's started by cron, it'll inherit from the cron daemon; if it's started by systemd, it'll inherit from that; etc.